# date comparison in python - how to know which semester date

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-datetime

I am somehow stuck in logical thinking.

I am going to compare date for this two states:

1. Summer semester (beginns on 16.04 - ends on 14.10)
2. Winter semester (beginns on 15.10 - ends on 15.04)

all including vacations

how do i check what semester this month/day in?

```
current_month = datetime.datetime.now().month
current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
current_day = datetime.datetime.now().day

if current_month>=10 and current_day>=15:
   #winter semester
```

but i am somehow doing it too chaos. is there any python lib for date comparison for my problem?

Comment: Why would a timedelta help here?

Comment: I was under the impression that datetime had built in comparison methods, so that you can just take raw datetimes and compare them using >,<,<=,>=,etc and get True or False out of that? without even having to care about slicing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could generate the summer dates:

```
current = datetime.date.today()
summer = current.replace(month=4, day=16), current.replace(month=10, day=14)

if summer[0] <= current <= summer[1]:
    # summer semester
else:
    # winter semester
```

This use a `datetime.date()` object instead of a `datetime.datetime()`, as the time portion is irrelevant here. The `date.replace()` calls make sure we reuse the current year.

This all assumes, of course, that summer semester starts and ends on the same dates each year.

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> current = datetime.date.today()
>>> current
datetime.date(2013, 9, 3)
>>> summer = current.replace(month=4, day=16), current.replace(month=10, day=14)
>>> summer[0] <= current <= summer[1]:
True
```

Comment: i feel very content that i am in python, cos there are wonderful people out there like you who can help... thanks dude. very big help!

Comment: +1 nice answer, a small suggestion: You can use a `namedtuple` here because something like `summer.start`, `summer.end` will look more appropriate than indexes.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I considered it; but felt it would be a little too verbose for a quick demo.

Comment: I think the condition `if summer[0] <= current <= summer[1]:` is probably a little more natural.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to create a lookup table (this is often a good idea when you have many disjointed time intervals, but each is a discrete size, like a day).

Another would be to test whether it is summer - after April 16 and before October 15. If it's not summer, it's winter. Works great when you just have two intervals - breaks down (messy code) if you have many more.